# A question regarding the existence of a walk in a variation of a graph.

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I came across the following question in an Algorithms course (I hope it fits Math Stack Exchange and if it doesn't, I apologize):

Let $ G=\left(V,E\right) $ be an undirected and connected graph with $ s,t\in V $ and $P$ a path from $s$ to $t$.
Prove: There exists a walk that uses every edge of $E-P$  **once in each direction** and uses every edge of $P$ **twice in each direction**.

The suggested solution is as follows:

Create a directed graph $G'$ by swapping every edge of $P$ with with **two pairs** of antiparallel edges, and swap every edge of $E-P$ with **a pair** of antiparallel edges.
Here's the part I don't understand: The new graph, $G'$, supposedly contains an Eulerian circuit, which is supposed to be the requested walk.

Now, the new graph should, in theory, have an Eulerian circuit. According to Wikipedia:

A directed graph has an Eulerian cycle if and only if every vertex has equal in degree and out degree, and all of its vertices with nonzero degree belong to a single strongly connected component.

I tried drawing an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLO6y.jpg) and its new graph (with the antiparallel edges) does not contain a circuit. I just can't find what I'm missing.

Comment: The graph you drew actually does have an Eulerian circuit. Start at t, walk back on forth on the purple edges to each of the adjacent vertices, then move up the green trunk up-down-up again, then left-right-left again, then back and forth on the purple branch, then two back-and-forths to s, then come back to t.

Comment: I see, I was looking at it from a geometrical point of view. I completely missed the definition of a cycle graph, simply being start and finish at the same vertex. Thank you!